# Eloquent hasMany with foreign key on joint table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

Assume this:

```
class List extends Model
{
    public function items(){
        return $this->hasMany(Items::class, 'c.class_id', 'class_id')
            ->rightjoin('items_classes as c', 'c.items_id', '=', 'items.id');
    }
}
```

The problem is that Eloquent prepends `items` to foreign key field and the final query is:

```
SELECT * FROM items
RIGHT JOIN items_classes as c ON c.items_id = items.id
// here it is
WHERE items.c.class_id = 10
```

Even using `DB::raw('c.class_id')` didn't solve the problem.

Comment: What is your query building code looking like? How do you define your query? Also, is it good practice to also do a right join in a relationship method?

Comment: I agree with @Fjarlaegur. It isn't a good practice to do a right join on relationship methods. Instead, make a new method, reuse this method there and attach a right join there. Also, where is the `where` condition written that you showed?

Comment: @Fjarlaegur I really have no idea what do you mean by "What is your query building code looking like?". The query is generated by this relationship function.

Comment: @vivek_23 Would you give me a link to any documentation that purposes such a solution? I need an example.

Comment: @Omid For methods that define relationships, there shouldn't be any additional stuff attached to it. This would make it execute every time whenever `items()` is called even when sometimes it wouldn't be needed.This would make it tightly coupled.  Instead make a new method and attach this method to it with the right join. Also, if the query is generated by this method itself, then there is some `boot()` method executing, attaching this `where` condition every time it's executed. Can you show us that method?

Comment: @vivek_23 I have posted all the things I want to do. There is no additional method to show you. Also I'm not going to add any extra where clause to the relationship query. This `where` condition is the default behavior of Eloquent builder and wanted to change it. However, I found out this is not going to be solved and the Laravel core needs some changes. https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/1528

Comment: @Omid `This where condition is the default behavior of Eloquent builder` That is never the case. Laravel only defines relationships and enables `joins` accordingly. Have you checked if there is any `boot()` method in any of your models' definitions? See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#global-scopes) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you notice the signature of `hasMany` relation method :

```
return $this->hasMany(Model::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

Which means when Laravel will make  the query, it will consider second argument `foreign_key` as a column of `table` defined in `Model::class`.

To simplify in your case :

```
return $this->hasMany(Items::class, 'c.class_id', 'class_id')->...
```

Leaving the rightjoin aside for a moment, Laravel is considering `c.class_id` as a foreign key of `Item::class` table which is indeed `items` table.

So the resultant query is  :

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE items.c.class_id = 10
```

Then when you add the right join, laravel just adds into  the main query and makes it :

```
SELECT * FROM items
RIGHT JOIN items_classes as c ON c.items_id = items.id
WHERE items.c.class_id = 10
```

Laravel will not refer `items_classes` in the relation because you are relating `List` Model to `Item::class` and not `ItemClass::class`.

I am not sure about the data you need but see if you can use with like below :

```
class List extends Model
{
    public function items(){
        return $this->hasMany(Items::class, 'c.class_id', 'class_id');
    }

}


List::with(['items', function($q){

    return $q->->rightjoin('items_classes as c', 'c.items_id', '=', 'items.id');
}])->get();
```

Hope this gives you an idea how you can update your relationships to get desired query. If you add your table structure and data you want, I can update the answer with relationships for you.

Comment: Thanks for spending time on my issue. However, I found this is not going to solve anyway but with overriding hasMany method.
https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/1528